# NSDictionary with same object key

Tags: objective-c, nsdictionary

i have a NSDictionary with arrays
A1: a,b,c,d,e,f and 
A2:1,1,1,2,2,3

i want to get the objects of key 1

i used:

```
[dicitonay objectsForKey: @"1"];
```

but i am get only 1 object, how to get all objects?

Comment: Looks like your wishful thinking influences even your *spelling*. It's `objectForKey`, not `objectsForKey`, so guess what? Dictionary is not a multimap, it's a "single" map.

Comment: i am looking for all objects of key@"a";

Comment: @AntonKovalenko: is there any other way to get it

Comment: @PradeepKumar if you want to keep multiple objects per dictionary entry, store e.g. `NSSet`s into your `NSDictionary`.

Answer (score 0):

If your dictionary contains two arrays, when you do 'objectForKey', one of the arrays(a single array object) will be returned. Without looking at your actual code, you should now have a single array object. You can use the typical array methods to access the objects inside the array.